# how to make this binary search tree work??? (in Java)

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, insertion

```
public void insert(int data) {
        if (root == null) root = new AVLNode(data);
        else {
            AVLNode node = root;
            while (node != null) {
                if (node.data <= data) {
                    node = node.right;
                }
                else {
                    node = node.left;
                }
            }
            node = new AVLNode(data);
        }
    }
```

im trying to make a binary search tree (nonrecursive) and then later on access is and do a preorder traversal, but when i print root i only get 1 element. all the insertions work, i think, but then root just has the first insertion in it and its left and right dont refer to anything, i think thats why im only getting 1 element. how do i refer root to the top of the node tree?
here is the node class btw

```
class AVLNode
{
    AVLNode left, right;
    int data;

    /* Constructor */
    public AVLNode()
    {
        left = null;
        right = null;
        data = 0;
    }
    /* Constructor */
    public AVLNode(int n)
    {
        left = null;
        right = null;
        data = n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the reference of variables. While loops until reaching a null value on `node` variable and then you assign the new node to it. But there is no link between the parent `node.left` or `node.right` and the new `node` variable because it has a `null` value assigned. So you are assigning the value to a variable not linked to anything and it will be lost. You need to assign new nodes directly to the `node.left` or `node.right` like this example:

```
public void insert(int data) {
   if (root == null) {
      root = new AVLNode(data);
   } else {
      AVLNode node = root;
      AVLNode newNode = new AVLNode(data);
      while (node != null) {
         if (node.data <= data) {
            if (node.right == null) {
               node.right = newNode;
               node = null;
            } else {
               node = node.right;
            }
         } else {
            if (node.left == null) {
               node.left = newNode;
               node = null;
            } else {
               node = node.left;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```